# AngularJS: Insert HTML from a string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, string

I've looked a LOT for this, but I either I can't find the answer or I don't understand it.  A specific example will win the vote =)

- I have a function that returns an HTML string.
- I can't change the function.
- I want the html represented by the string to be inserted into the DOM.
- I'm happy to use a controller, directive, service, or anything else that works (and is reasonably good practice).
- Disclaimer:  I don't understand $compile well.

Here's what I've tried:

```
// My magic HTML string function.
function htmlString (str) {
    return "<h1>" + str + "</h1>";
}

function Ctrl ($scope, $compile) {
  $scope.htmlString = htmlString;
}
Ctrl.$inject = ["$scope", "$compile"];
```

That didn't work.

I tried it as a directive too:

```
// My magic HTML string function.
function htmlString (str) {
    return "<h1>" + str + "</h1>";
}

angular.module("myApp.directives", [])
  .directive("htmlString", function () {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: { content: "@" },
      template: "{{ htmlStr(content) }}"
    }
  });

  ... and in my HTML ...

  <html-string content="foo"></html-string>
```

Help?

*Note*

I looked at these, among others, but couldn't make it work.

- [AngularJS : Insert HTML into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs)
- [AngularJS $http HTML Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141080/angularjs-http-html-parser)
- [angularjs - inserting $compile-d html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737795/angularjs-inserting-compile-d-html)
- [AngularJS doesn't execute in HTML inserted with document.write()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656533/angularjs-doesnt-execute-in-html-inserted-with-document-write)
- [Escape HTML text in an AngularJS directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462612/escape-html-text-in-an-angularjs-directive/14514299#14514299)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Have a look at the example in this link :

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.$sanitize

Basically, angular has a directive to insert html into pages. In your case you can insert the html using the ng-bind-html directive like so :

If you already have done all this :

```
// My magic HTML string function.
function htmlString (str) {
    return "<h1>" + str + "</h1>";
}

function Ctrl ($scope) {
  var str = "HELLO!";
  $scope.htmlString = htmlString(str);
}
Ctrl.$inject = ["$scope"];
```

Then in your html within the scope of that controller, you could

```
<div ng-bind-html="htmlString"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  Made some edits:  Fixed the link (SO parsed it weirdly), changed "ng-bind-html" to "ng-bind-html-unsafe", and gave a more full example.

Comment: It's `ng-bind-html-unsafe` up until 1.0.8, after that it's just `ng-bind-html` because the safe and unsafe functions were merged https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#120-rc1-spooky-giraffe-2013-08-13

Comment: @AakilFernandes, I had to add ```ngSanitize``` to my main module for ```ng-bind-html``` to work.

Answer (score 15):

you can also use `$sce.trustAsHtml('"<h1>" + str + "</h1>"')`，if you want to know more detail, please refer to [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)