# HTML String does not display correctly

Tags: javascript, html, angular

It has been a while and I know there is a solution.  I am retrieving an object from Firebase 3.  The field is a string containing html. I am inserting the value into an Angular2 component.html. Is there a way, function call, method to render the html without the `<b>` tag in Angular2?

```
   key: Description
   value: <p>Hello World</p>
```

[image]

In my Angular component HTML

```
   <h3>Description</h3><div>{{something.Description}}</div>
```

The html is render as:

[image]

Comment: Yes there is. Check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778709/prevent-angular-from-escaping-html

Comment: @user7326764 This is not an Angular2 solution.

Answer (score 2):

A few ways to acheive this:

**1) Try using the `.append` method of angular instead.**

`<h3>Description</h3><div id='divID'></div>`

```
var myElement = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#divID' ) );
myElement.append('<p>Your values/variables</p>');
```

**2) For Angular 2:**

```
<div [innerHTML]="theHtmlString">
</div>
```

**3) For those that come across this still using Angular 1 vs 2:**

A different way, is `ng-bind-html`, something like so:

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.myHTML =
     '<h3>Description:</h3>' +
     '<div> YOUR VARIABLES </div>';
}]);
```

Comment: I'd suggest removing the `ng-bind-html` portion of your answer, only because it may confuse readers who stumble upon this question in the future - it is not correct, as OP has specifically stated he's looking for an Angular 2 solution. **EDIT:** Nice edit :)

Answer (score 2):

`ng-bind-html` (as many are suggesting) is not an Angular2 solution. Use `[innerHTML]` instead.

```
<div [innerHTML]="something.Description"></div>
```