# Angularjs html tag is showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add the following code.

```
$scope.journals = [
   {title: "Journal", content: "This is content <br>"}
]
```

The HTML that I have is:

```
<div ng-repeat="journal in journals">
   <h1>{{journal.title}}</h1>
   <span>{{journal.content}}</span>
</div>
```

However the "br" Tag is showing as just plain text and not html. How can I fix that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS: Insert HTML from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761724/angularjs-insert-html-from-a-string)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DrtNc/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to mess with $sce and you just want to get er done:

```
lrApp.directive('bindHtml', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.bindHtml,function(nv,ov){
            elem.html(nv);
        });
    }
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can work for you but you can use a combination of `ng-bind-html` with `$sce.trustAsHtml()` to mark your content as trusted.  Note that you'll only want to do this if you can truly consider the content as safe.

Here's a plunk as an example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/L51T4OxdF8AFF5lRQdQW

Here's the `$sce` documentation.  Worth a read IMHO to understand the impact of `trustAs`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use [ng-bind-html directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml), provided by angularjs

```
<span ng-bind-html="journal.content"></span>
```