# Angular render markup that is nested

Tags: angularjs

I get JSON like this

```
{
 "lots of":"keys"
 "description" : {
   "key":"Some sample key",
   "value":"This is the markup&trade;"
  }
}
```

from server and I ultimately iterate the description objects and populate table rows with two columns: one for the key and one for the value.

I have tried putting on my `<td>` tag `ng-bind-html` as well as injecting `$sce` into my controller and using `trustAsHtml` but so far the string always displays as it is in the JSON. Not every value will be HTML but I can easily detect based on the key if HTML is a possibility.  It seemed when I put in the directive on the `td` it did not display anything if no HTML was present. I am interested in using something that can allow HTML in the value but not require it so I can display either

HTML fragment

```
  <tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in record.description">
                        <td>{{key}}:</td>
                        <td>{{val}}</td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: Can you post the code the iterates over the JSON and prints it?

Comment: And, are you sure that it is json and not just text? JSON.parse and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a quick fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/frishi/mvw97s3q/6/

I used `angular-sanitize`, which I am not sure you mentioned injecting in your module dependency list. Either way, the example works simply by using `ng-bind-html`

Relevant docs page: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

It works by using the directive `ng-bind-html` on the element you want to display the HTML string in. You use it like so:

`<p ng-bind-html="data.firstName"></p>`

assuming that `data.firstName = "<strong>FeeFee</strong>"` or something like that.

I would also like to add that Angular does not allow this natively because of legitimate security concerns. That and the fact that allowing arbitrary HTML to be rendered might not always produce desirable results. Your page layout could quite possibly break because of some HTML you allowed to be passed through.

Comment: selected this answer because of the fiddle since ```ng-bind-html``` wasn't working without including ngSanitize in the module ( I had over looked this)

Answer (score 1):

Angular was designed with security in mind, and will prevent you from displaying HTML from raw strings whenever possible - to prevent various injection attacks.

Here is workarround for your problem: [AngularJS: Insert HTML from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761724/angularjs-insert-html-from-a-string). Generally you should use `ng-bind-html` insted of `ng-bind` (this is used by curly braces).