# AngularJS converting the '/' to '%2F in url

Tags: angularjs

I have a routeprovider:

```js
 $routeProvider.when("/editor/:tripName*", {
              controller: "tripEditorController",
              controllerAs: "vm",
              templateUrl: "/views/tripEditorView.html"
          });
```

and in html something like :

```html
<td><a ng-href="#/editor/{{ trip.name  | escape}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Manage</a></td>
```

But when I click on the button, my url is getting converted to something strange

/App/trips#!/#%2Feditor%2FIndia%2520Trip

Appreciate any pointer to get this fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: Insert HTML from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761724/angularjs-insert-html-from-a-string)

Comment: @Vipin Have you fixed the bug? I have faced it also and I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

`ng-href` directive don't require hash in the value. try like below.

```
<td>
  <a ng-href="editor/{{ trip.name  | escape}}" 
      class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Manage</a>
</td>
```

Refer below Pages:
Doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref
Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: Thanks but it is a single-page application and removing the # doesn't help. I am landing to the main page and then want to move to other part of page using this ng-href

Comment: you are using ng-href, please share the working sample

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the code you are trying to edit the trip details, rather than getting details from trip name get it by id, because name may have space , dash etc. and while redirecting URL will get change.

Answer (score 0):

only add an ! sign after hash as some cases work like that